# Finding information in parts of txt document and storing them in variables

Tags: c++, variables, search, ifstream

I have a large .txt document holding information. It is structured in this kind of format:

```
ID: 54670
Gender: M
Name: John Doe
Address: Blah Blah Blah
Email: JohnDoe@.com
```

I'm trying to create a program that allows one to enter the ID. The program will find the ID in the text document and then store the ID,Gender,Name,Address, etc.. in variables.
I can search for the ID and print following lines. But I'm lost on how to store particular parts of each line and only storing the info from say 5 lines after finding the ID. This is all i have so far. Any pointers would be much appreciated. I have just started teaching myself to code in the last couple weeks. So you are all such a great resource.

```
struct userInfo
{
    int id;
    char gender;
    std::string name,address,email;
};
std::string search,line;
std::ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("iData.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
    std::cout << "Was unable to open file!";
    return 1;
    }

        std::cout << "Enter I.D" << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, search);

            while (inFile.good())
            {
                std::getline(inFile, line);
                if (line.find(search) != std::string::npos)
                {
                    std::cout << line << std::endl;
                }
            }
inFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create

```
map<int,list<string>>
```

Later parse your file once and split each line and store those value in your map

```
//Example code to fetch data from line
    std::getline(inFile, line);     
    int pos = line.find(":");
    std::string val  = line.substr(pos+1, line.length());
```

after that you can just use

```
List<string> details = map.find[id];
```

Comment: Knew i could count on this place. I have a few books but none of them mention maps. I appreciate your help. I have some refinements to do but you have helped me take a big step forward. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the file once and save the info in map so when given id you can get the info map[id].gender